# Displaying text in Javascript failing with PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have been changing over some old code in some of my files to use PDO, i have done it a good few times with no problems but on this occasion the javascript is not fully executing after the change over.

**Code:**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);

    // INCLUDES //
    include('../includes/db_connection_quick.php');
    include('../includes/functions.php');

    // VARS //
    $cid           = (int)$_GET['c'];
    $aid           = (int)$_GET['p'];

    // GET CONTENT LOCKER DATA //
    $contentLocker = DB::getInstance()->selectOneByField('content_lockers', 'content_locker_id', $cid); 
    $surveys       = array();
    $randSurveys   = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `offers` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5');


    // OLD CODE //
    //if (!$cid || !$aff_id) exit;
/*  $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DATA);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    // query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM content_lockers WHERE content_locker_id = $cid";
    if ($res = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $locker_data = $row;
        }
    }
    if (empty($locker_data)) exit;

    $show_count = 5;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM offers ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0, $show_count";
    $surveys = array();
    if ($res = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $url_parts = parse_url($row['offer_url']);
            parse_str($url_parts['query'], $params);
            $params['cid'] = $cid;
            $params['aff_id'] = $aff_id;
            $url_parts['query'] = http_build_query($params);
            $surveys[] = "<a href='https://www.payday-dreams.co.uk/click.php?c={$row['offer_id']}&cl=$cid&p=$aff_id' target='_blank'>{$row['offer_title']}</a>";
        }
    }

    if (empty($surveys)) exit;*/
    // OLD CODE //

    // LOOP RANDOM SURVEYS AND ADD TO THE $surveys ARRAY //
    foreach ($randSurveys as $s) {
            $surveys[] = "<a href=\"https://www.site1.co.uk/click.php?c={$s['offer_id']}&cl={$cid}&p={$aid}\" target=\"_blank\">{$s['offer_title']}</a>";       
    }   

    $text = "<h1 id='locker_main_text'>
          . <img src='https://www.site1.co.uk/images/locked.png' id='locker_icon' />{$contentLocker['content_locker_main_text']}</h1>"
          . "<p id='locker_sub_text'>{$contentLocker['content_locker_sub_text']}</p>"
          . "<p id='locker_surveys'>" . join('<br />', $surveys) . "</p>";
    $text = str_replace("\n", '', $text); 

?>

var jQ = false;
function initJQ() {
  if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
    if (!jQ) {
      jQ = true;
      document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
    }
    setTimeout('initJQ()', 50);
  } else {
    (function($) {
    $(function() {

        $('body').append("<div id='locker_background'><div id='locker_message_area'><?php echo $contentLocker['content_locker_main_text']; ?></div></div>");
        $('#locker_background')
            .css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px',
                bottom: '0px',
                left: '0px',
                right: '0px',
                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.65)'
            });
        $('#locker_message_area')
            .css({
                background: '#fff',
                width: '500px',
                //height: '200px',
                margin: '0 auto',
                position: 'fixed',
                left: '50%',
                top: '50%',
                marginLeft: '-265px',
                marginTop: -$('#locker_message_area').outerHeight() / 2,
                padding: '15px',
                boxShadow: '0px 0px 15px 10px #444',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                borderRadius: 8,
                background: '#222',
                fontFamily: '"Open Sans", sans-serif'
            });
        $('#locker_main_text')
            .css({
                fontSize: '14pt',
                padding: '0px',
                margin: '0px 0px 10px 0px',
                color: '#B90D0D'
            });
        $('#locker_sub_text')
            .css({
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '9pt',
                color: '#25BC13',
                textAlign: 'center',
                padding: '0px',
                margin: '14px 0px 14px 0px'
            });
        $('#locker_surveys, #locker_surveys a')
            .css({
                fontSize: '10pt',
                lineHeight: '1.3',
                color: '#fff',
                padding: '0px',
                margin: '0px'
            });
        $('#locker_icon')
            .css({
                marginRight: '10px',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                padding: '0px',
                margin: '0px'
            });

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#locker_background, #locker_message_area').fadeOut(600, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, <?php echo $contentLocker['content_locker_pause'] * 1000; ?>);

    })
    })(jQuery)
  }
}
initJQ();
```

I have placed the old code within the "**// OLD CODE //**" blocks, it's a fairly basic script, it worked great before, the issue seems to be with the **$surveys** array, this is where it only loads half way as if it's having issues displaying, there is no errors being displayed from the PHP side, nothing from the **$text** downwards was touched it remained the same, can anyone see any glaring issues i may have missed? appreciated.

Comment: _"there is no errors being displayed from the PHP side"_. That tends to happen when you supress them: `error_reporting(0);`. Change that to `error_reporting(1);`

Comment: any console warnings/errors? also enable error reporting in you PHP

Comment: Oh what i meant was, there is no errors coming from PHP at all, meaning everything works well from that side, here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/4ovSYin.jpg this shows the box attempting to load, below "Unlock this Page to Continue!" is where the offers should display, but it doesn't get that far.

Comment: I believe that: foreach ($randSurveys as $s) {
            $surveys[] = "<a href=\"https://www.site1.co.uk/click.php?c={$s['offer_id']}&cl={$cid}&p={$aid}\" target=\"_blank\">{$s['offer_title']}</a>";       
    } is where the issue lies, this is new code i added which i thought would work well but doesn't seem to print to screen.

Comment: Well I'd start with `die($text);` at the end of your PHP file to see if it actually contains the data you're expecting. If that's fine, you know for sure the issue lies with Javascript.

Comment: Just tried it icecub, it displays exactly what i want, so these 2 lines:     . "<p id='locker_sub_text'>{$contentLocker['content_locker_sub_text']}</p>"
    . "<p id='locker_surveys'>" . join('<br />', $surveys) . "</p>"; are the ones failing it seems, i will keep debugging.

Comment: "***there is no errors being displayed from the PHP side***"  that's because you've disabled error reporting with `error_reporting(0);` - enable it by adding  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  and run the script again.

Comment: @PedroLobito Ye, that was like the first comment made to the question and OP already explained that he ment there were no errors.

Comment: The results of the die($text); (https://i.imgur.com/btmgYJP.jpg) this is showing great, absolutely no errors to show from PHP, THE $surveys array is failing to show, this is a strange one.